# ZF2 Redirect out of Controller

Tags: zend-framework2

Before all, sorry for my poor english.
Good night/day/afternoon (depending of your location)
Sorry if I ask something that could be searched here, and I searched, even found it, but maybe I di not understand.
I need to check authentication in my controllers, so, I implement a master controller and extend all my real controllers to it. In my master controller I check authentication and do it well, but when I try to redirect an unauthenticated user it crashes!
Searching in web, I realized that "init, preDispatch, etc" methods even don't exist more, just the "construct" method, so I try in it, but in construct there is not an event manager, so I stop here...
This is my code:

```
public function __construct(){
    $r = new SimpleRouteStack();
    $r->addRoute('logoff', Literal::factory(array(
                                                'route'=>'/suporte/logoff',
                                                'defaults' => array(
                                                    'action'     => 'logoff',
                                                  'controller' => 'Suporte\Controller\Index',
                                                )
                                        )
                            )
    );
    $e = new MvcEvent();
    $e->setRouter($r);
    $this->setEvent($e);
    $this->getEvent()->setResponse(new Response());
    $this->getEventManager()->attach('*',array($this,'mvcPreDispatch'),100);

public function mvcPreDispatch(){
    $uri = explode('/',substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1));
    $uri[2] = !isset($uri[2]) ? "index" : $uri[2];
    $auth = new AuthenticationService();
    $identity = $auth->getStorage()->read();
    $acl = $identity[2];

    if (!$auth->hasIdentity()){                                     
        $this->redirect()->toRoute('suporte/logoff');
    }elseif (   !$acl->hasResource($uri[0].'/'.$uri[1])             
                                        ||                          
                !$acl->isAllowed($identity[1],                      
                                $uri[0].'/'.$uri[1],                
                                $uri[2]                             
                            ) 
            )
                $this->redirect()->toRoute('logoff');
        else{
            /* $this->layout()->id = $identity[0]->getId();
            $this->layout()->nome = $identity[0]->getNome();
            $this->layout()->cargo = $identity[0]->getCargo(); */
            echo "permitido";
            //$this->layout()->recursos = $this->acl->getResources();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is your `Suporte\Controller\logoff` also extending the masterclass. If yes then it will lead to an infinite loop `indexController>masterController(!loggedin)>logoutController>masterController(!loggedin)>logoutController>..`

Answer (score 0):

How I used to say "IT is witchcraft"!!!
When I wake up today, turn on my computer, test the controller and BAZINGA!!! is running ok...
Why? I don't dare to question...
my code is that:

```
abstract class PadraoControllerSuporte extends AbstractActionController{
public function setEventManager(EventManagerInterface $events){
parent::setEventManager($events);
$controller = $this;
$events->attach('dispatch', function ($e) use ($controller) {
    if (is_callable(array($controller, 'verificaAuth'))){
        call_user_func(array($controller, 'verificaAuth'));
    }
}, 100);
```

}

```
public function verificaAuth(){
    $uri = explode('/',substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],1));
    $uri[2] = !isset($uri[2]) ? "index" : $uri[2];
    $auth = new AuthenticationService();
    $identity = $auth->getStorage()->read();
    $acl = $identity[2];
    if (!$auth->hasIdentity())                                      
        $this->redirect()->toRoute('suporte/logoff');
    elseif (    !$acl->hasResource($uri[0].'/'.$uri[1])                                 !$acl->isAllowed(   $identity[1],
                                    $uri[0].'/'.$uri[1],            
                                    $uri[2]                         
                                ) 
            )
                $this->redirect()->toRoute('logoff');
        else{
            /* $this->layout()->id = $identity[0]->getId();
            $this->layout()->nome = $identity[0]->getNome();
            $this->layout()->cargo = $identity[0]->getCargo(); */
            echo "permitido";
            //$this->layout()->recursos = $this->acl->getResources();
        }
}
```

What I understood:
I think that "setEventManager" was superimposed, so it sets to listen the "dispatch" event and call my verificaAuth function what redirects (if not authenticated) to logoff or allow it is authenticated.
Hope this is usefull...
Thanks for all!!!